# Loop through rows and create objects to File Management system

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to create loop to add members to our File Management system. This works and is adding members however there is a problem with "For each cel" I guess. It looks like my solution takes each cell in range and creates new object. So in range `A3:C5` there is 9 cells and I get 9 objects.

My intention is to create loop that will create 3 objects with code. So it should look like this:

1. Take name from A3 and then collect properties to it from offsets (PD Name Or title B3 and PD Address C3).
2. Take name from A4 and then collect properties to it from offsets (PD Name Or title B4 and PD Address C4).
3. Take name from A5 and then collect properties to it from offsets (PD Name Or title B5 and PD Address C5).

Here is my simplified code:

```
'set range
    Dim myrng: Set myrng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("A3:C5")

Dim cel
'loop through each cell in range
For Each cel In myrng

'collect dearch memebers
Set oSearchCondition = CreateObject("MFilesAPI.SearchCondition")
oExp.DataPropertyValuePropertyDef = 0
oTV.SetValue MFDatatypetext, cel.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value
oSearchCondition.Set oExp, MFConditionTypeEqual, oTV
oSearchConditions.Add -1, oSearchCondition

'Execute search

'Collect property memebers

    ' PD Name Or title.
    oPVNew.PropertyDef = 0
    oPVNew.TypedValue.SetValue MFDatatypetext, cel.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value
    oPVsNew.Add -1, oPVNew

    ' PD Address
    oPVNew.PropertyDef = 1028
    oPVNew.TypedValue.SetValue MFDatatypetext, cel.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=2).Value
    oPVsNew.Add -1, oPVNew

' Create a new document collection if it doesn't already exist
If oObjectSearchResults.Count = 0 Then

    ' Create New one
    Set oDocumentCollectionOVAP = oVault.ObjectOperations.CreateNewObjectEx(305, oPVsNew)

Else

End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the first column of `myrng` only.

```
For each cel in myrng.Columns(1).Cells
```

Otherwise, you are looping through every cell in `myrng`, which is 3 columns long by definition.

Alternatively, you can change the definition of `myrng` and keep your for loop the same.

```
Dim myrng: Set myrng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("A3:A5")
```